# How can I use default CPT templates from sub-folder?

Tags: templates

Is it possible to move 'default' CPT templates (example: single-cpt_name) to a sub-folder and still have WP recognise and auto-assign them?

If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use [`single_template`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/single_template) filter hook to load your template from a subdirectory. The full code will be like below-

```
function the_dramatist_get_custom_post_type_template($single_template) {
    global $post;

    if ($post->post_type == 'your_post_type') {
        // Your post type directory with the post type template file name
        $single_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/post-type-template.php';
    }
    return $single_template;
}
add_filter( 'single_template', 'the_dramatist_get_custom_post_type_template' );
```

Please read the documentation for further information. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, excellent. With this the theme root is less cluttered, and the required template can be in a sub-sub-folder (example: templates/cpt-name/template-name.php).